# Class 'Validator' not found in Lumen

Tags: php, validation, laravel, lumen

try to create validator manually in Lumen. The official documentation is written:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Store a new blog post.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
     }
}
```

I wrote

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController,
    Validator;

class Welcome extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            ['test' =>'TestValidation'],
            ['test' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255']
        );
    }
}
```

but Lumen returns fatal error:
**Fatal error: Class 'Validator' not found in ...**

I have tried to do like in Laravel 5:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

but then Lumen returns
**Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in**

Somebody knows how to use the Validator class in Lumen? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Validator is a facade. Facades aren't enabled by default in lumen.

If you would like to use the a facade, you should uncomment the

```
$app->withFacades();
```

call in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Comment: I Love you :* xoxox

Answer (score 1):

This is for Lumen version 5.3 (as shown in the docs):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$app->post('/user', function (Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
 ]);

    // Store User...
});
```

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation